# Does "Logan" have continuity with X-men movies? Which ones?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, wolverine, logan

So we know the event's of 2013's *The Wolverine* took place in the original timeline. So just HOW does Logan have the Samurai sword in "Logan"? I guess the events of *The Wolverine* still could have ended up happening in the revised timeline, but that seems unlikely.

Also, how does Charles remember the Statue of Liberty incident? That also happened in the original timeline. But then again, that could've happened in the revised timeline as well, I guess. Or maybe Charles' mind is so powerful that he can remember events that happened in a whole other timeline?

Comment: Pretty sure they're meant as Easter Eggs that continuity isn't supposed to apply to.

Comment: I guess I can understand that as far as the Samurai Sword goes, but Charles mentions the Statue of Liberty event in an oddly specific manner. That seemed like more than an Easter Egg to me.

Comment: Is this _the_ sword though? Not a random sword Logan could have acquired elsewhere, and kept as memorabilia?

Comment: Say it with me now: "There is no continuity in X-Men. There is no continuity in X-Men. There does not NEED to be continuity in X-Men. There is no continuity in X-Men."

Comment: Not *everything* changed with the timeline alteration.

Comment: Xavier is still a very powerful psychic; he could easily be drawing memories from Wolverine's mind when he mentions the statue of liberty (or had previously done so, or Wolverine told him details of the other timeline at some point) and maybe confusing then with his own memories.

Comment: Just to add a wrinkle to it, *The New Mutants* includes footage from the labs in *Logan*, which further muddles continuity.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer has two parts:

1. *Logan* doesn't bother with continuity unless it wants to, and
2. Fox has left the "events" of the 2000's in the new timeline basically undocumented , so they can be whatever they need to be.

When Fox made *Days of Future Past* their intent was to try to undo some of the mess they'd made of their canon timeline in the previous movies, as well as some of the silly things (Hi, "mute Deadpool"!). The producers at Fox were pretty clear that *Days of Future Past* basically negated the events of *X-Men Origins: Wolverine* and *X-Men 3*.

But all that means is, the events *as they happened in those movies* didn't necessarily happen that way anymore. In other words, Fox isn't bound to maintain continuity with those movies. However, there's no reason to assume that none of those events happened. It's reasonable to expect that some of those things were bound to happen anyway, especially when you look at something like *The Wolverine*, where the events were triggered by something that happened before the timeline split. So, if Fox wants to claim that *something* traumatic still happened at the Statue of Liberty, they're free to do so; we as viewers can just imagine that those events happened in a way that's "reasonably similar" to the first movie. But, if Fox wants to claim something different happened to, for example, Jean Grey, we can just ignore those parts of *X-Men 3* that contradict the new story.

On top of that, though, the *Logan* writers and directors were pretty open about the fact that they weren't going to feel bound by previous movies if they thought they could improve their own. (It's hard to reconcile the *Logan* timeline with the end of *Days of Future Past* in the first place.) When you're talking about something as minor as an off-hand comment or Easter egg, you just have to accept that sometimes they're going to diverge from strict continuity for the sake of entertainment.

Comment: [src](http://www.empireonline.com/movies/features/logan-trailer-breakdown-james-mangold-talks-us-first-teaser/)

Comment: This answer does better than all those on other questions to sum up the whole canonicity/continuity situation with Logan.

Answer (score 5):

I would argue that the simple answer is that director James Mangold didn't really care for the alternate timeline/reboot stuff that began with *First Class* and decided to make a sequel to *The Wolverine*, meaning ***Logan*** takes place in the **original timeline.**

There are a lot of indications of this being the case, such as the fact that the 2029 future of this world looks radically different from the bright, happy, mutant-filled 2023 of the DOFP post-credit scene. Note that, here, the idea is that no mutants have been born for 25 years, which doesn't make sense at all in the context of DOFP.

Moreover, the movie only makes references to the original timeline, such as Wolverine being a cage fighter. Several deleted scenes had more of this, including Prof X discussing how Wolverine killed Jean and Logan recalling being part of the same squad with Sabertooth. Finally, Mangold confirmed that Wolverine's death at the end of Logan fulfills Yukio's prophecy in *The Wolverine.*

As such, *Logan* indicates that *First Class* was already set in a different timeline and DOFP's Sentinel-ruled 2023 presented the future of that specific timeline. This means *First Class, DOFP, Apocalypse* and (maybe) *Deadpool* are part of a singular, rebooted continuity, while X1-3, and the *Wolverine* trilogy are still in the original.

Comment: If you could back this up with some actual evidence it would go from being a reasonable answer to a great one. You're probably not wrong, but what are you basing it on?

Answer (score -1):

Don't forget, the Sentinels were about to kill all the mutants in 2023, and the timeline changed at last-minute-dot-com, and there's at least 3 mutants in 'Logan' (i.e: Wolverine, Charles and Laura (AKA 'X-23')) (which is set in 2029), thus placing 'Logan' in the new timeline.

Also, everything from the original timeline prior to 1973 and after 1973 may have changed. Part of 'X-Men Origins Wolverine' still happens in the new timeline (until the screen goes blank after Logan left Team X (or whatever they were called) in 1973).

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You appear to mostly be talking about things that _don't_ match in continuity, but the question was about what things _do_ keep continuity, and to what extent, overall, continuity is maintained.  Please make sure that your answers actually address the question.